# Yet another "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named X"

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa

I'm converting an old eclipse IVY Project to maven. In the old project it used eclipselink, and I'd like it to use hibernate.

I've created a couple of projects using Hibernate, so I used my persistence.XML from those, and changed the parts that needed to be changed.

Though I'm experiencing a problem; It can't find my persistence provider.
In my pom, I've tried using the hibernate-core dependency, and the hibernate-persistence-provider - none worked.

As for now, my pom is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>test.dk</groupId>
<artifactId>test-test</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>4.1</version>
<name>test</name>

<prerequisites>
    <maven>3</maven>
</prerequisites>

<properties>
    <vaadin.version>7.7.8</vaadin.version>
    <vaadin.plugin.version>7.7.8</vaadin.plugin.version>
    <jetty.plugin.version>9.3.9.v20160517</jetty.plugin.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <!-- If there are no local customisations, this can also be "fetch" or "cdn" -->
    <vaadin.widgetset.mode>local</vaadin.widgetset.mode>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-addons</id>
        <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin.addon</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-charts-model</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin.addon</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-charts</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>batik</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-bridge</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>batik</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-gvt</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-anim</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.vaadin.addon</groupId>
        <artifactId>confirmdialog</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>batik</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-util</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>batik</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-svggen</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>batik</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-svg-dom</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>batik</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-dom</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.snmp4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>snmp4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.ethz.ganymed</groupId>
        <artifactId>ganymed-ssh2</artifactId>
        <version>262</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <!-- Exclude an unnecessary file generated by the GWT compiler. -->
                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets/WEB-INF/**</packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update-theme</goal>
                        <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                        <!-- Comment out compile-theme goal to use on-the-fly theme compilation -->
                        <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <!-- Clean up also any pre-compiled themes -->
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/styles.css</include>
                            <include>**/styles.scss.cache</include>
                        </includes>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- The Jetty plugin allows us to easily test the development build by
            running jetty:run on the command line. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- Vaadin pre-release repositories -->
        <id>vaadin-prerelease</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>

        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
                <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
            </repository>


            <repository>
                <id>vaadin-addons</id>
                <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
            </repository>


            <repository>
                <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
                <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
                <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
            </pluginRepository>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
                <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And my persistence.XML

```
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
         version="2.1">
<persistence-unit name="Test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/stabilitydb2?useSSL=false"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="PASSWORD_ON_STACKOVERFLOW"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>

        <!-- Configuring Connection Pool -->
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="500"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="2000"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

And I have ensured the persistence.XML is located in the resources

[image: Resources folder]

Though I keep getting the error

```
Jun 07, 2017 9:58:52 AM com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler doDefault
SEVERE: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named Test
```

And the code for creating the entitymanager (I know it's not threadsafe - sry.)

```
public class FactoryMaker {

    /**
     * The entity manager factory.
     */
    private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    /**
     * Gets the factory - singleton
     *
     * @return the factory
     */
    public static EntityManagerFactory getFactory() {
        if (entityManagerFactory == null)
            entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Test");

        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

}
```

This is working in all other projects. What is going on? I have tried deleting my repo, and reimporting. No dice.

Really hope somebody can help me.

Best regards.

Comment: has the file really got a suffix "XML" (capitals)? Perhaps fix that

Comment: Tried that. Suppose intellij corrects changes it to capital letters. Just checked my old projects, all are captial letters, and working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is akward.

The problem was the mysql-connector...

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

was missing.

Comment: mysql connector is required for all data base connections to MqSql db irrespective of JPA/JDBC.